# How to see more information for queued Jobs in SLURM

Tags: cluster, slurm

With `srun --test-only` SLURM will return expected start date AND expected nodes.

However, if the job is submitted, I cannot get the information about the nodes. Is there any way to find out, what nodes a job is expected to run on when the job is already submitted?

`squeue --start` only gives the expected start date but not the expected nodes.

I'm using SLURM 2.5.7.

Answer (score 0):

That is corrected in version 14.11. From the NEWS file:

```
* Changes in Slurm 14.11.0pre1
============================== 
[...]  
-- Modify squeue --start option to print the nodes expected to be used for
    pending job (in addition to expected start time, etc.).
```